# If the data type changes from string to bool data store is throwing an error

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

I am storing my struct values in google data store. Here is my struct:

```
type Appointment struct {
    ID                    string 
    Appointment Date      string 
    Start Time            string 
    End Time              string 
    Select Specialization string 
    Smoking Status        string
}
```

I have stored some data using datastore, but later changed the data type from string to bool for the field "Smoking Status" then the data store is throwing an error:

> {"error":{"message":"data store: cannot load field \"Smoking Status\" into a \"simplysthealth.Encounter\": type mismatch: string versus bool"}}

Is there any feasible solution for this?

Comment: You previously stored records are stored as string. but now you are inserting/updating/querying boolean data. so it's a type mismatch.

Comment: You should choose a flexible datastore, else you have to store all data again manually whenever you change the type/structure of your dataset.

Comment: If my client asks  to change the datatype .what can i do.there is no soultion

Comment: You may store the data manually. i am answering the question with an example code.

Comment: Google data store is not providing any feasible solution for these .Is there are any data stores that are flexible

Comment: Can  you show me the example code so that i may understand

Comment: I've already answered, And I think you got the point out!

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

// I have corrected all of your method names
type Appointment struct {
        ID                   string
        AppointmentDate      string
        StartTime            string
        EndTime              string
        SelectSpecialization string
        SmokingStatus        string
}

type AllOldData struct {
        Data []Appointment
}
type FixedAppointment struct {
        ID                   string
        AppointmentDate      string
        StartTime            string
        EndTime              string
        SelectSpecialization string
        SmokingStatus        bool
}

type FixedData struct {
        Data []FixedAppointment
}

func TypeFixing() FixedData {

        var OldData AllOldData
        var NewData FixedData

        OldData = GetYourAllOldData()

        for i, v := range OldData.Data {
                if v.SmokingStatus == "true" {
                        // other value exchanging
                        NewData.Data[i].SmokingStatus = true
                } else {
                        // other value exchanging
                        NewData.Data[i].SmokingStatus = false
                }
        }

        return NewData // Save the data in a new table or whatever you call it

}

func GetYourAllOldData() AllOldData {
        // A function that returns all old data
        return AllOldData{} // You must return return your all data
}
```

This is what you need to do it manually!

Comment: Is these a feasible solution really i am in dialema